# Is pendingURL always defined for tabs.onCreated(function(tab){})?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Will the `pendingURL` property always be defined for tab argument of a `tabs.onCreated` callback function?
I'm trying to decide whether or not I also need to check tab.url, as in this

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (newTab)
{
  if(newTab.pendingUrl === extensionURL || newTab.url === extensionURL) 
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

Thanks for any insight you can give.

This is my first question here so any feedback on how to better post questions is welcome.

Comment: Feedback: use a more meaningful title. As it's currently written it's really unclear what your post is about, there's no question in the title. Also, the "Chrome Extension Dev" part is useless, it's already implied by the fact that you tagged with google-chrome-extension.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I'll be sure to have an actual question in the title next time and try not to have any redundancy with tags.

Comment: You can also edit the title or body of the post if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's defined only when there's a pending navigation that didn't resolve visually in the browser's address bar. Once Chrome decided to proceed (which happens after finally connecting to the remote server), it'll change the URL in the address bar and that'll be the end of "pending".

There's no guarantee whether it'll be present or not because it depends on the asynchronous events in the network stack and the way the OS schedules processes at this particular moment. The Chromium's source code simply has an `if` check [there](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/extensions/extension_tab_util.cc;l=463;drc=2008132d15b80d8af2af6ba90d4b3353c52c6901?sq=package:chromium) so it doesn't assume anything.

Do it like this:

```
if ((newTab.pendingUrl || newTab.url) === extensionURL) {
  //....
}
```

or

```
const url = newTab.pendingUrl || newTab.url;
if (url === extensionURL) {
  //....
}
```

Comment: I understand basically what pendingUrl is for, I'm asking if, specifically within the `tabs.onCreated`  event, it will consistently be defined.
Thanks for mentioning the
`if ((A || B) === C)`
trick, I'm used to `A || B` returning a bool.

Comment: There's no guarantee because it depends on the asynchronous events in the network stack and the way the OS schedules processes at this particular moment. The chromium's source code simply has an `if` check [there](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/extensions/extension_tab_util.cc;l=445-448?q=CreateTabObject&sq=package:chromium) so it doesn't assume anything.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I'll keep the check and just put the pendingUrl part first.