# How can I add a listener to a Chrome tab after it has been opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that listens for newly created tabs, and does logic based on their URL:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    // Do logic with "tab.url"
});
```

But the `tab.url` field is frequently empty. According to the documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated) the URL will not be populated until the page starts loading, but I don't know how to add this secondary listener or what to listen to in order to get the desired behavior.
To be clear, the type of event I am looking to detect is a **newly opened tabs that have a url already** for example a user opening a link in a new tab, not a new tab that the user types a url into.

Comment: Listen for onUpdated event so you can know when the user types a url

Comment: Check `tab.pendingUrl`. See [Is pendingURL always defined for tabs.onCreated(function(tab){})?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60445157)

Comment: @wOxxOm Will either `tab.pendingUrl` or `tab.url` always be defined in all tab opening situations?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: @SaymoinSam That is what my question is asking how to do, please leave an answer with an explanation on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

This might work-

```
const CHROME_NEW_TAB_URL = 'chrome://newtab/';

const onCreatedListener = (tab: chrome.tabs.Tab) => {
  if (
    tab.pendingUrl === CHROME_NEW_TAB_URL
  ) {
    // this was opened by user manually
  } else {
    // this is result of a link click
  }
};
```